# Maximum number of combinations in sequence

Tags: permutations, combinations

I don't know how to formulate this exactly, but I have a sequence of $4$ numbers: sequence$=x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$ and $x_i\in\{1,2,3,...,24\}$. I need to know how many unique sequences that exists. For example, $1,5,23,14$ is one unique possibility. I hope it makes sense!

Comment: is sequence 1,5,23,14 equal to 5,1,14,23 ?

Comment: No, they are both unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the $x_i$ gets to choose from $24$ choices, so there are $24^4$ unique sequences.